# How can I prevent numbering of ordered list <ol> adjust to accommodate hiding / unhiding elemtents

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have an ordered list, such that some list items `<li>` are, by default hidden via css. These can be revealed (via JavaScript) depending on user behaviour however.

If they are revealed the entire list reorders so that they are in sequence, while when they were hidden the list had no breaks in sequence.

I would like each element of the list (even the ones that start hidden) to have fixed number in the list, even if this means that on page load the list will have gaps (1. 2. 4. 5. etc)

In this case the list would only appear an unbroken list of elements by number, if all elements were revealed.

**Here is a jsfiddle illustrating my problem**
http://jsfiddle.net/hesxT/1/

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Are you asking how you change the numbers on the numbered list items?

Comment: In Firefox, your page behaves exactly as you are describing you want. But in IE7, it doesn't allocate a number to hidden list items.

Comment: @Gideon Please see my updated answer, which works cross-browser. The answer you selected does not work in IE7 when it is applied within a class and the class is removed--the child elements of the hidden item are not rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hesxT/6/

use...

```
visibility: hidden;
height: 0;
```

to hide the item.  Then remove those properties to make the item visible.

and, as others have pointed out, remove the `<div>` wrapping the `<li>`, it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this out, but in my real page I think I need to keep the div (it serves to contain the entire sectino that is hidden, not just the li)

Comment: You can do that if you want to, but `<div>` is invalid content in that context: `<ol>` allows only `<li>` as immediate children. Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/ol), [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), and [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element).

Comment: Indeed, I just can't see a way I can generate the numbered lists I need as well as all the other functionality. I've tested my solution across all browsers I can find and it works, so I'll settle for now. Thank you for your help it worked out.

Comment: @Gideon Please ask a separate question about how to avoid the div and I am SURE people will be able to help you. But you need to post an example that we can play with. Please tag me with the link if you do ask the question!

Comment: @ErikE many thanks for the kind suggestion: I've created the quesiton and tagged you in a comment, unsure if it tags if you haven't been involved in the discussion, so just in case, it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13480092/1486796

Answer (score 1):

The li element has an attribute 'value' which can be used to set the value of the number list item.

```
<ol>
    <li value='1'>Item 1</li>
    <li value='3'>Item 3</li>
    <li value='4'>Item 4 </li>
    <li value='5'>Item 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How many browsers support this? I didn't think this was well-supported yet.

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/ol-element-attributes/ seems to indicate that the value property is currently supported by the main browsers. It is also in the w3c specifications: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/li and http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Comment: @dmi3y - It _was_ deprecated but [now it's not](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li.attrs.value).

Comment: @dmi3y True, it is no longer deprecated: w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html

Comment: thank you guys, did not know about it, sitepoint cheated me :P

Answer (score 0):

I made some modification to your code. Check this out,

http://jsfiddle.net/hesxT/2/

**Code:**

```
$('li').each(function(i){
    $(this).html((i+1)+'. '+$(this).html());
});
$('#myform').change(function() {
    if ($('#reveal').attr('checked')){
        $('#hide').show();
    } else {
        $('#hide').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Removing the numbers of the ordered list and adding them in the html instead is not good. There's not only no need to do that but if the OP wanted to use hard-coded numbers he probably would have. Using an `ol` will indent properly, as well, while your solution will not.

Comment: This seems ingenious, however I have several li elements which are unorered and as @ErikE mentions I rely on indenting etc of ol, one of the reasons I haven't hard coded the numbers

Comment: Note that you can simplify this solution by removing the `.each()` loop, because `.html()` accepts a callback: `$('li').html(function(i,oldHtml){ return (i+1)+'. '+oldHtml; });`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem you're describing in Firefox 16. But it apparently happens in earlier versions of Firefox and in IE (I only tested IE 7).

So this is what you need that will work cross-browser:

```
.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In IE, using the other suggested answers will prevent the child elements of the hidden element from displaying properly when the hidden class is removed through script.

Also, screen readers may or may not present the hidden content how you expect, but that may not be a concern.

Note: It is not valid to wrap the `li` element in a `div` element. For those interested see [this question about fixing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480092/styling-html-li-elements-avoiding-an-invalid-parent-div/).

Comment: I agree that a div should not wrap an li element, but I just tried your fiddle and it has the same problem as the original.

Comment: Hmmm what browser are you using?

Comment: Interesting that it's not valid to wrap a `<li>` in a div - in my actual code I am numbering a set of questions which are deep in nested divs (i.ee each question has a set of three divs required for all sorts of positional things etc) how should I be numbering these questions if not with <li>?

Comment: I tested with Firefox 11.0. (I know it's not the latest, but I haven't been able to upgrade due to restrictions imposed from above in my organisation.)

Comment: I could be wrong about divs wrapping an li being invalid. But why can't you put the divs inside the lis? You can style lis in all sorts of ways.

Comment: It's definitely not valid ([an li element's permitted parent elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context) are ol, ul and menu), but as with most invalid html the browser will do its best to cope regardless. But because it's not valid different browsers may give you different results...

Comment: Well, my situation is this: A page of questions, each numbered. 

Any one question, is contained in a div which has a label, and input within it. The label contains <li> </li> so that each question label is numbered. 

I need to hide entire questions (which appear based on answers to other questions).

In this case,you think I could put the <li> outside the div?

Comment: Why can't you put the label inside the li, give the li relative positioning, then position the label absolutely so it moves outside of the li as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using CSS and toggleClass which uses automatic numbering on the list:

```
.hidden {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AMvp8/